# Does Jmeter set variables at runtime that 'locate' the test file directory?

Tags: jmeter

When starting Jmeter I see some evidence that Jmeter might be setting some variables called 'base'  and 'testFilesDirectory' .  Does anyone have experience using those variables and are they accessible?

```
jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='C:\Users\x\ws\test\target\jmeter\bin' 
jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\Users\x\ws\test\src\test\jmeter\Tests.jmx 
jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\Users\x\ws\test\src\test\jmeter'
```

And this:

```
[DEBUG]   (f) propertiesReplacedByCustomFiles = true
[DEBUG]   (f) resultsFileFormat = xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skipTests = false
[DEBUG]   (f) suppressJMeterOutput = true
[DEBUG]   (f) testFilesDirectory = C:\Users\x\ws\test\src\test\jmeter
[DEBUG]   (f) testResultsTimestamp = true
[DEBUG]   (f) workDir = C:\Users\x\ws\test\target\jmeter
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access these variables [using Beanshell](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as follows:

1. JMeter's base dir

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

   String baseDir = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();
   vars.put("baseDir", baseDir);
   ```
2. JMeter's script location (GUI mode)

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;

   String testPlanFile = GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();
   vars.put("testPlanFile", testPlanFile);
   ```
3. JMeter's script name (non-GUI mode)

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

   String scriptName = FileServer.getFileServer().getScriptName();
   vars.put("scriptName", scriptName);
   ```

If you prefer you can get the same using [__Beanshell()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__BeanShell) function as

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir())}
```

and it will return current base directory where it is called.

Comment: I knew about the methods you show above, but my theory is that getting those values might be even simpler because Jmeter 'appears to be' setting them for the user at runtime?